# Select rows from table1 and (row=row_from_table1) from table2

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables. From first I want to select all rows and from table2 row=row_from_table1.

What i mean:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS value_sum, itemid_table1, itemname, date, cost FROM bets
```

and

```
SELECT participate FROM items WHERE itemid='itemid_table1'
```

Is possible to do it in one query with returning value_sum, itemid_table1, itemname, date, cost and participate?

Comment: Yes, read about SQL-Joins. Also, it seems like your first query isn't right, you are missing a group by clause, unless all the columns are the same except from the amount column which I highly doubt.

Comment: Any example close to my aim?

Comment: Yes, google: `MySQL joins`, `SQL Tutorial` ,`MySQL Group by`

Comment: This is not "Do my homework assignment" site, always try something on your own!

Comment: I understand you, but i just ask for simple example CLOSE to my aim, not done homework ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go through this link.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

In your case, you can try.

```
SELECT SUM(b.amount) AS value_sum, b.itemid_table1, b.itemname, b.date, b.cost, i.participate
FROM bets b INNER JOIN items i ON b.itemid=i.itemid_table1
WHERE b.itemid='DESIRED_VALUE_HERE'
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! Thank to you I uderstand how it works ;)

Comment: you're Welcome. please mark it right by clicking right sign